# Adding SQL Scripts to TFS Build Process

Tags: sql, azure, tfs

our team currently updates our production databases via the dacpacs/bacpacs since we do not have any client data.  This will not be the case in the near future and I'm looking to change the process of only modifying the database via SQL scripts via build automation.

Is managing these SQL scripts in Team Foundation Server and executing them in the build do-able? And If so how have people approached this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not be deploying DACPACs during the build process; it's more appropriate to push changes as part of a release/deployment workflow that occurs after a build.

That said, you can publish a DACPAC without dropping the database and recreating it; there are numerous options for controlling the database publishing behavior that can be set at the project level and overridden at the command line if necessary.

Comment: Right, we want to move forward with process of managing SQL scripts and running these scripts against the database for updating schema and adding data.  Is publishing DACPAC's the best way for that still?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways of managing SQL data base changes when deploying to production.

1. **DACPAC**
2. **Sequential SQL Scripts**

Both have there own issue and bonus when trying to deploy. If you control your entire DevOps pipeline then Dacpac is a good option. If you have to deal with corporate dba's then SQL scripts can also be done.